# string format notation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

For the code below:

```
double j1;

j1=7000000    //example
ItemE[5]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@1. total inc = %g", j1];
```

ItemE[5] is returned as `"1.total inc = 7e +06"`

How do I prevent the scientific notation and have `"1.total inc = 7000000"` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%f`:

```
ItemE[5]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@1. total inc = %f", j1];
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want decimal places you should use:

```
ItemE[5]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@1. total inc = %.f", j1];
```

To elaborate, you were using wrong specifier in format string.`%g` instructs to create string representation of floating-point variable in scientific notation. Normally you should use `%f` to represent `double` and `float` variable. By default, this specifier will result in number with 6 decimal places. In order to change that you can modify that specifier, for example:

`%5.3f` means that string should have 3 decimal places and should be 5 characters long. That means that if representation would be shorter than 5 chars, string will have additional spaces in front of number to give 5 chars total. Note that if you will have large number, it'll not be truncated. Consider code:

```
double pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288;
NSLog(@"%f", pi);
NSLog(@"%.3f", pi);
NSLog(@"%8.3f", pi);
NSLog(@"%8f", pi);
NSLog(@"%.f", pi);
```

will give result:

```
3.141593
3.142
   3.142
3.141593
3
```

Comment: And, for reference, the docs for `stringWithFormat:` have a link to a “String Format Specifiers” page.

Comment: (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) for those who want a convenient link

Comment: @Phillip Mils well, then i get  7000000.000000  I don't need the after the decimal point digits. do i need to convert to to integer or is there a format way here  ?

Comment: Got to the link that @Vervious gave you and then click on where it says, "For more details, see the IEEE printf specification."

Comment: @Johnnywho, yes, i just got the same after digging some more :). ty.

Answer (score 2):

please, try to use this one:

```
double j1 = 7000000.f;
NSLog(@"1. total inc = %.f", j1);
```

the result will be:

```
1. total inc = 7000000
```

I hope it helps.